# Inner join within table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `categories` with the following fields:

```
id, content, is_subcategory, topic_id
```

Here comes an examplatory set of data:

```
id  content       is_subcategory reference_id
=============================================
1   Games         0              989898989
2   Xbox          1              1
3   Playstation   1              1
4   Furniture     0              121212121
5   Sofa          1              4
6   Closet        1              4
7   Music         0              989898989
8   Pop           1              7
9   Reggae        1              7
```

Explanation:

- If the category is a subcategory, its reference_id is the id of the parent category. For example, `Sofa` has 4 as its reference_id as 4 is the id of Furniture.
- If the category is a parent category, its reference_id is the id of another table `topics`. For example, `Music` is a parent category and has 989898989 as its reference_id which is the id for the topic "entertainment".

How do I achieve that I can select only those **sub**categories whose parent category has 989898989 as its reference_id?

Comment: School work? Do a self join (different table aliases).

Comment: Really? You are using the column reference_id to denote two different things linking to two different tables? What happend? Are columns to expensive for your budget that you have to recycle them? It would be a lot better if you just used a column id_parentcategory and a column id_topic with foreign keys to the respective tables. In that case you can delete the is_subcategory column as that would be redundant. If a category has a parent category then it is a subcategory.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Not a very nice way to put that, but I agree. Max, 1 column should do 1 thing.

Comment: @Rudie Yes you are right. I'm sorry, I do not mean to offend anyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can do just like it was 2 different tables:

```
select * from categories c, categories parent
where c.reference_id=parent.id and parent.reference_id=989898989 and c.is_subcategory = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM category sub, category super WHERE
sub.reference_id = super.id AND super.reference_id = 989898989
AND sub.is_subcategory = 1
```

Since you alredy figured out that you need a self join for this question I am sure you can understand my solution. If not, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Give different aliases and try

```
SELECT id,content FROM `categories` Child  INNER JOIN 
 `categories` Parent ON Child.`reference_id` = Parent.`id`
WHERE Parent.reference_id=989898989 and Child.is_subcategory = 1
```

I like to suggest **inner join**  for better perfomance.

Comment: Inner join instead of outer join? No need for outer join here anyway.